# Cannot opacity and resize the watermark image in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, gd, watermark

I want to resize and add opacity to the watermark image but i can't. I don't know what wrong with my code please help me. TT

this is my code.

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
$config['source_image'] = $image_url;
$config['new_image'] = $image_url;
$config['wm_overlay_path'] = $watermark_url;

$config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
//the overlay image
$config['wm_opacity'] = 30;
$config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'middle';
$config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';

$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['width'] = 50;
$config['height'] = 50;
$config['padding'] = 50;
$config['wm_vrt_offset'] = 100;

$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->watermark();
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

Comment: does it output some errors?
$this->image_lib->display_errors();

Comment: No it doesn't have any error but the image output it cannot resize or opacity the watermark image TT

Comment: Opacity is working for me, but I think the image library doesn't have the option to specify a width or height to the watermark. See the docs: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html#image-watermarking